# Is there a way to add a custom variable to Shopify checkout link?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, shopify, liquid, shopify-app

My client has a Shopify store that sells a single product. In order to buy that product one has to first preorder it with a downpayment, get approved and only then he can buy the product. In order to enforce the approval procedure my client would like to make each purchase link (checkout link) unique and only send those who got approved a link for an active single use checkout.

Is there a way to take a unique ID (or any parameter that is not related to the cart) and inject it into the url?

Answer (score 0):

You can accept orders for "preorder" products and then manually create a Draft Order in the admin panel and "invite customer" to open that order and complete it via email. No need to code anything :)

Comment: In addition to what @TwistedOwl presents, Shopify also has new payment options such as Pre-order, that work to legally allow the merchant to sell without collecting full payments. You can check that out too!